# I would like to annotate new column 'is_like' in Django

Tags: django

i use this queryset

```
<Queryset[<UsePoint:a>,]>
<name:a, like_users_count:3>
```

my code:

```
        user_exists = User.objects.filter(
            pk=self.request.user.pk,
            pk__in=OuterRef('like_users'),
        )
        queryset = queryset.annotate(is_like=Exists(user_exists))
```

i think it return one queryset like this

```
<Queryset[<UsePoint:a>,]>
<name:a, is_like:true, like_users_count:3>
```

but It returns two queryset

```
<Queryset[<UsePoint:a>,<UsePoint:a>]>
<name:a, is_like:false, like_users_count:2>
<name:a, is_like:true, like_users_count:1>
```

how can i distinct these result?

```
#model
class UsePoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'UsePointCategory',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    like_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
user_exists = User.objects.filter(
   pk=self.request.user.pk,
   pk__in=OuterRef('like_users'),
).first()
```

it will return a single object

Or you can use

```
user_exists = User.objects.filter(
   pk=self.request.user.pk,
   pk__in=OuterRef('like_users'),
).distinct()
```

It will retun distinct object

Comment: add your model defination

Comment: add my model defination

Comment: what `user_exists` value return?